Bug Byte puzzle from Jane Street
This is a puzzle from Jane Street.
Given this graph:

Fill in the edge weights in the graph with the numbers 1 through 24, using each number exactly once. Labeled nodes provide some additional constraints:

This solution below correctly solves the puzzle, but it takes around 5 minutes to complete on my laptop. I'm a bit rusty on algorithms, so I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to solve it. Any feedback is appreciated.
After building the graph, this is the high level logic of the function solve:

Assign a (candidate) weight to an edge
Check if the state of the graph is correct (validation)
If the validation fails, backtrack and try with another weight
If the validation is correct proceed to the next edge recursively
When there are no more edges the solution is found

Note: running the code won't reveal the secret message, uncomment the last line if you want to see it.
Code:
from collections import deque
import networkx as nx
import string
import time


class Node:
    def __init__(self, id, sum_edges, paths=[]):
        self.id = id
        self.sum_edges = sum_edges
        self.paths = paths

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Node):
            return self.id == other.id
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Node(id={self.id},sum_edges={self.sum_edges})"


class Graph:
    def __init__(self, nodes):
        self.g = {}
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.edges = {}
        # Available weights
        self.aw = {}
        # Number of edges
        self.E = 0
        self.candidates = {}

    def add_edge(self, s_id, t_id, w=None):
        """
        Adds an edge to the graph with an optional weight
        """
        self.edges[(s_id, t_id)] = w
        self.edges[(t_id, s_id)] = w
        if s_id in self.g:
            self.g[s_id].add(t_id)
        else:
            self.g[s_id] = {t_id}

        if t_id in self.g:
            self.g[t_id].add(s_id)
        else:
            self.g[t_id] = {s_id}

        self.E = len(self.edges) // 2
        self.update_aw()

    def update_aw(self):
        """
        Updates available weights (aw). Available weights are weights 
        not assigned to any edge. 
        """
        self.aw = {i + 1 for i in range(self.E)}
        weights = {w for w in self.edges.values() if w}
        self.aw = self.aw.difference(weights)

    def update_candidates(self):
        """
        Updates candidate weights for each edge. Candidate weights are available weights 
        that can be assigned to an edge according to the state of the graph.  
        """
        self.candidates = {}
        for edge, w in self.edges.items():
            if not w:
                sid, tid = edge
                ub = self.upper_bound(sid, tid)
                candidates = [w for w in self.aw if w <= ub]
                self.candidates[(sid, tid)] = candidates

    def set_w(self, sid, tid, w):
        """
        Set weight w to the edge identified by source node id (sid) and 
        target node id (tid). Then update available weights and candidates.
        """
        self.edges[(sid, tid)] = w
        self.edges[(tid, sid)] = w
        self.update_aw()
        self.update_candidates()

    def unset_w(self, sid, tid):
        """
        Unset weight w of the edge identified by source id (sid) and target id (tid).
        Then update available weights and candidates.
        """
        self.edges[(sid, tid)] = None
        self.edges[(tid, sid)] = None
        self.update_aw()
        self.update_candidates()

    def upper_bound(self, s_id, t_id):
        """
        Determines the upper bound weight for the given edge according to the state of the graph.
        """
        s = self.nodes[s_id]
        t = self.nodes[t_id]

        def upper_bound(s, t):
            if not s.sum_edges:
                return self.E
            tot = 0
            aw = self.aw.copy()
            for neighbor_id in self.g[s.id]:
                if neighbor_id != t.id:
                    if self.edges[(neighbor_id, s.id)]:
                        tot += self.edges[(neighbor_id, s.id)]
                    else:
                        tot += min(aw)
                        aw.remove(min(aw))
            return min(self.E, s.sum_edges - tot)

        return min(upper_bound(s, t), upper_bound(t, s))

    def print_edges(self):
        seen = set()
        res = {}
        for edge, weight in self.edges.items():
            if edge in seen:
                continue
            a, b = edge
            seen.add((a, b))
            seen.add((b, a))
            res[edge] = weight
        print(res)

    def validate(self):
        """
        Validates the state of the graph:
        - The sum of all edges directly connected to a node
        - The paths (see function validate_paths)
        """
        for node in self.nodes:
            if node.sum_edges:
                tot = 0
                # if all direct edges set then has to equal to sum_edges
                if all(
                    self.edges[(node.id, neighbor_id)]
                    for neighbor_id in self.g[node.id]
                ):
                    if (
                        sum(
                            self.edges[(node.id, neighbor_id)]
                            for neighbor_id in self.g[node.id]
                        )
                        != node.sum_edges
                    ):
                        return False
                else:
                    for neighbor_id in self.g[node.id]:
                        if self.edges[(node.id, neighbor_id)]:
                            tot += self.edges[(node.id, neighbor_id)]
                    if tot > node.sum_edges:
                        return False
        if not self.validate_paths():
            return False
        return True

    def validate_paths(self):
        for node in self.nodes:
            if node.paths:
                for N in node.paths:
                    if not self.validate_path(node, N):
                        return False
        return True

    def validate_path(self, root, N):
        """
        Validates requirement:
        - There exists a non-self-intersecting path starting from this node where N is the sum of the weights of the edges on that path
        """
        seen = set()
        q = deque([(root.id, N)])
        while q:
            node_id, limit = q.popleft()
            seen.add(node_id)
            if limit == 0:
                return True
            if limit < 0:
                continue
            for neighbor_id in self.g[node_id]:
                if neighbor_id not in seen:
                    w = self.edges[(node_id, neighbor_id)]
                    if not w:
                        return True
                    q.append((neighbor_id, limit - w))
        return False

    def shortest_path(self, sid, tid):
        """
        Finds the shortest path between the given nodes
        """
        G = nx.Graph()
        G.add_nodes_from([node.id for node in self.nodes])
        for edge, w in self.edges.items():
            aid, bid = edge
            G.add_edge(aid, bid, weight=w)
        return nx.shortest_path(G, source=sid, target=tid, weight="weight")

    def decode_path(self, p):
        """
        Converts a path to the secret message
        """
        res_w = [self.edges[(p[i - 1], p[i])] for i in range(1, len(p))]
        alp = [0] + list(string.ascii_uppercase)
        message = [alp[w] for w in res_w]
        return "".join(message)

    def solve(self):
        """
        Solves the graph by finding the configuration of weights that satisfies the requirements
        """
        self.update_candidates()
        progress = len(self.edges) // 2

        def solve(edges):
            nonlocal progress
            if not edges:
                return True
            sid, tid = next(iter(edges))
            remaining_edges = {
                key: value
                for key, value in edges.items()
                if key != (sid, tid) and key != (tid, sid)
            }
            if len(remaining_edges) // 2 < progress:
                progress = len(remaining_edges) // 2
                print(f"Remaining edges to solve: {progress}...")
            # if the edge already has a weigth assigned, skip to next
            if edges[(sid, tid)]:
                return solve(remaining_edges)
            # Try every candidates for the given edge if there are any
            if self.candidates[(sid, tid)]:
                for w_candidate in self.candidates[(sid, tid)]:
                    self.set_w(sid, tid, w_candidate)
                    if self.validate() and solve(remaining_edges):
                        return True
                    # unset failed candidate
                    self.unset_w(sid, tid)
            return False
        return solve(self.edges)


def main():
    nodes = [
        Node(0, 17),
        Node(1, 3),
        Node(2, None, [19, 23]),
        Node(3, None),
        Node(4, None, [31]),
        Node(5, 54),
        Node(6, None, [6, 9, 16]),
        Node(7, 49),
        Node(8, None, [8]),
        Node(9, 60),
        Node(10, 79),
        Node(11, None),
        Node(12, 29),
        Node(13, 75),
        Node(14, None),
        Node(15, 25),
        Node(16, None),
        Node(17, 39),
    ]
    g = Graph(nodes)
    g.add_edge(0, 1)
    g.add_edge(0, 2)
    g.add_edge(1, 3)
    g.add_edge(2, 3, 12)
    g.add_edge(2, 5)
    g.add_edge(3, 7)
    g.add_edge(4, 5)
    g.add_edge(5, 9)
    g.add_edge(9, 7)
    g.add_edge(7, 8)
    g.add_edge(6, 9)
    g.add_edge(5, 10)
    g.add_edge(9, 10, 24)
    g.add_edge(9, 13)
    g.add_edge(7, 13, 20)
    g.add_edge(10, 11)
    g.add_edge(10, 12)
    g.add_edge(10, 17, 7)
    g.add_edge(12, 17)
    g.add_edge(12, 15)
    g.add_edge(13, 14)
    g.add_edge(13, 15)
    g.add_edge(15, 16)
    g.add_edge(16, 17)
    
    print("Total number of edges: ", g.E)

    start_time = time.time()
    g.solve()
    end_time = time.time()

    running_time = end_time - start_time
    print("Running time:", running_time, "seconds")
    p = g.shortest_path(3, 16)
    secret_message = g.decode_path(p)
    # Uncomment to see the solution
    #print(f"The secret message is: {secret_message}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I don't understand the N constraint. There exists a non-self-intersecting path starting from this node... to where?

@Reinderien to any node except the node itself. Yeah, that part is a bit confusing

This submission would benefit from the addition of
profiling
measurements.
mutable default
This signature has
well-defined semantics.
But please don't do it.
Human maintenance engineers in future
will have difficulty reasoning about it.
class Node:
    def __init__(self, ..., paths=[]):

Here, let me demonstrate:
>>> n1 = Node(1, 1)
>>> n2 = Node(2, 2)
>>> n1.paths.append('one')
>>>
>>> n2.paths
['one']

I confess that, in the course of trying to "begin again" for
a clean demo, I accidentally assigned n2.paths = [].
Uggh! Yeah, rookie mistake, do you see it?
I meant to do n2.paths.clear(), which means something entirely different.
Standard idiom for this would be
    def __init__(self, ..., paths=None):
        ...
        self.paths = paths or []

equality
I don't understand what's going on with __eq__.
It seems to suggest that e.g. Node(3, 20) == Node(3, 30).
That's certainly feasible, there are business domain use cases
where that would be desirable.
But in this particular puzzle I'm just not seeing how that makes sense.
Also, it's not clear that you even use this and need to define it at all.
Similarly for __hash__.
Not sure why we would even want a pair of Node 3's to exist.
signature
    def __init__(self, id, sum_edges, paths=[]):

When I read the constructor I thought I understood what was going on.
I didn't.
Here is how I read it:
    def __init__(
        self,
        id: int,
        sum_edges: int,
        paths: list[Node] = [],
    ):

But it turns out later that sum_edges can be None instead of 0.
Please don't surprise the Gentle Reader with such non-obvious assignments.
Either spell it out in a """docstring""",
or offer a hint via type annotation.
Also, consider giving sum_edges a default value,
either 0 or perhaps None.
abbreviations
        # Available weights
        self.aw = {}
        # Number of edges
        self.E = 0

Thank you, thank you for that first comment, very helpful.
I would never have guessed that on my own,
but now I know how to mentally pronounce it, good.
That second item, for edges, is not so great.
Better to elide the comment and simply assign self.num_edges = 0.
As it stands, it's clear we have discarded the
pep-8 convention,
since E obviously isn't a class.
But that leaves me to fall back on math naming conventions,
yet \$E\$ obviously isn't a connectivity matrix or vector quantity.
Please choose a more appropriate name for this concept.
Or remove it entirely, as it doesn't seem to offer more
than len(self.edges).
You could offer that expression as a computed @property, if desired.
(Oh, I see later there's a surprising representation choice,
where an undirected graph of N edges induces a corresponding
digraph of 2 × N edges, ok.)
doubled edge
    def add_edge(self, s_id, t_id, w=None):
        """
        Adds an edge to the graph with an optional weight
        """
        self.edges[(s_id, t_id)] = w
        self.edges[(t_id, s_id)] = w

Thank you for the docstring, making it clear the last param is a weight.
The problem statement doesn't speak of \$s\$ or \$t\$ nodes,
so I started pronouncing them "src" and "to" (not "dst" and "from"?)
and then noticed they model an undirected edge
and decided they're just arbitrary letters.
[edit: OIC, source and target.]
Doubling the edge seems inconvenient.
For one thing, update_candidates() does everything twice twice.
We could maybe exploit sort order to quickly find the out edges
from \$s\$ or from \$t\$, but I don't notice any sorting happening.
Consider adopting the fairly conventional approach of assigning
        pair = tuple(sorted([s_id, t_id]))
        self.edges[pair] = w

so that each undirected edge has a canonical name, in numeric order.
defaultdict
This is inconvenient and needlessly distracting:
        self.g = {}
        ...
        if s_id in self.g:
            self.g[s_id].add(t_id)
        else:
            self.g[s_id] = {t_id}

Prefer to let
defaultdict
worry about details irrelevant to your core algorithm.
        self.g = defaultdict(set)
        ...
        self.g[s_id].add(t_id)

algorithm
update_aw() looks expensive, with work proportional to graph size.
Consider making "self.aw is always accurate" a class invariant,
and preferring incremental delta updates rather than rebuilding
it from scratch each time.
Doing the update_candidates() work incrementally would
be similarly attractive.
A tiny nit:
        self.aw = {i + 1 for i in range(self.E)}

Hoisting
the + 1 out of the loop lets us accomplish that
with fewer interpreted bytecodes:
        self.aw = {i for i in range(1, self.E + 1)}

or equivalently ... = list(range(1, self.E + 1)).
correctness
        def upper_bound(s, t):
            if not s.sum_edges:
                return self.E

This seems to assign unit weight in the "unknown" None case.
It's not clear to me how that would be correct.
I would have expected an expression closer
to self.E * max_edge_weight.
Also, I am troubled by the lack of symmetry with target node t.
The relationship between s.sum_edges and t.sum_edges
is not yet obvious to me.
It warrants an assert, or at least a docstring remark or comment.
graph representation
Modeling an undirected graph is not core to this code's contribution.
Consider outsourcing that to
networkX
or similar graph library.
They have already worked out the details for
things like undirected graph vs digraph,
with excellent documentation,
which saves you some effort.
OIC, you do wind up using that library,
to exploit its nx.shortest_path() routine, very good.
But each call is a bit expensive, as you
reproduce a new graph from scratch.
Consider relying on an nx.Graph as your core representation.
None vs empty container
    def validate_paths(self):
            ...
            if node.paths:
                for N in node.paths:

Consider simplifying it down to
            for n in node.paths or []:

Consider banishing None from your datastructure entirely,
replacing it with an empty container.
Often the None special case is just a distraction.
Iterating over zero items is a natural way to say "do nothing".
And kudos for using a deque during validation, that looks great.
nested function
I just don't even understand what's going on in here.
    def solve(self):
        ...
        progress = len(self.edges) // 2

        def solve(edges):
            nonlocal progress

Is the nesting buying you anything?
Certainly it has made it difficult to
unit test
this with the nested function inaccessible.
Yes, it's a recursive approach, but that's no excuse.
Please give the two functions two different names,
if only to make telephone conversations about this
code go more smoothly.

This problem can be solved optimally in pseudo-polynomial time. This can be done by using k-sum. For every edge that has two connected M nodes we can compute k-sum on both vertices then take the intersection of the possible values that sum up to both nodes to drastically reduce the search space. This reduces the complexity of the problem down to \$O(E * K^S)\$ where \$K\$ is the possible values in this case \$K\$ is 20, and \$S\$ is the k-sum complexity of the vertex with the maximum amount of edges needed to be filled. In this case \$S\$ is 3, due to the fact that the highest number of unfilled edges in the graph is 4 meaning 4 sum is the highest complexity any edge will require which has an \$O(N^3)\$ complexity. That makes this solution \$O(E * K^3)\$.
I wrote a similar version to yours with this implementation and mine runs in about .3 seconds. Here is the code, it's far from perfect and could use some optimizations.
Note: This version handles edges in sorted order based off of the amount of valid options in the k-sum result, this is a slight heuristic approach as filling in edges with the least amount of possibilities first will reduce the complexity of the higher order edges at every step,this results in the algorithm pruning the search space drastically by reducing the k-sum complexity of the higher bounded edges in each recursive call.
import heapq
import time
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import List


def twoSum(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    res = []
    s = set()

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if len(res) == 0 or res[-1][1] != nums[i]:
            if target - nums[i] in s:
                res.append([target - nums[i], nums[i]])
        s.add(nums[i])

    return res


def threeSum(nums, target):
    n = len(nums)
    triplets = []
    nums.sort()  # Sort the array in ascending order

    for i in range(n - 2):
        if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
            continue

        left = i + 1
        right = n - 1

        while left < right:
            current_sum = nums[i] + nums[left] + nums[right]

            if current_sum == target:
                triplets.append([nums[i], nums[left], nums[right]])
                left += 1
                right -= 1

                while left < right and nums[left] == nums[left - 1]:
                    left += 1
                while left < right and nums[right] == nums[right + 1]:
                    right -= 1
            elif current_sum < target:
                left += 1
            else:
                right -= 1

    return triplets


def fourSum(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    def kSumm(nums: List[int], target: int, k: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        res = []

        # If we have run out of numbers to add, return res.
        if not nums:
            return res

        # There are k remaining values to add to the sum. The
        # average of these values is at least target // k.
        average_value = target // k

        # We cannot obtain a sum of target if the smallest value
        # in nums is greater than target // k or if the largest
        # value in nums is smaller than target // k.
        if average_value < nums[0] or nums[-1] < average_value:
            return res

        if k == 2:
            return twoSum(nums, target)

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if i == 0 or nums[i - 1] != nums[i]:
                for subset in kSumm(nums[i + 1:], target - nums[i], k - 1):
                    res.append([nums[i]] + subset)

        return res

    nums.sort()
    return kSumm(nums, target, 4)


def k_sum(nums, target, k):
    if k == 1:
        for num in nums:
            if num == target:
                return [[num]]
    if k == 2:
        return twoSum(nums, target)
    if k == 3:
        return threeSum(nums, target)
    if k == 4:
        return fourSum(nums, target)
    return []


class Vertex():
    def __init__(self, i, sum_edges=None, intersections=None):
        self.i = i
        self.se = sum_edges
        self.intersections = intersections
        self.edges = []
        self.total_sum = 0


class Graph():
    def __init__(self, nodes):
        self.g = defaultdict(lambda: [])
        self.filled_edges = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.valid_weights = set([i for i in range(1, 25)])
        self.onstack = set()
        for i in [7, 12, 20, 24]:
            self.onstack.add(i)
        self.edges = {}
        self.attempts = 0

    def add_edge(self, v, w, c=None):
        self.edges[(v, w)] = c
        self.edges[(w, v)] = c
        self.g[v].append(w)
        self.g[w].append(v)
        self.nodes[v].edges.append(w)
        self.nodes[w].edges.append(v)
        if c is not None:
            self.nodes[v].total_sum += c
            self.nodes[w].total_sum += c
            self.filled_edges[v] = self.filled_edges[v] + 1
            self.filled_edges[w] = self.filled_edges[w] + 1
            self.onstack.add(c)

    def has_non_intersecting_path(self, v, visited, cost, target):
        if v in visited:
            return cost == target
        visited.add(v)
        for w in self.nodes[v].edges:
            c = self.edges[(v, w)]
            if cost + c == target:
                return True
            elif cost + c < target:
                if self.has_non_intersecting_path(w, visited, cost + c, target):
                    return True
        return False

    def valid(self):
        visited = set()
        used = set()
        sums = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
        for v, w in self.edges:
            if (v, w) in visited:
                continue
            if self.edges[(v, w)] is None or self.edges[(v, w)] in used or self.edges[(v, w)] not in self.valid_weights:
                return False
            visited.add((v, w))
            visited.add((w, v))
            used.add(self.edges[(v, w)])
            sums[v] += self.edges[(v, w)]
            sums[w] += self.edges[(w, v)]
        for v in self.nodes:
            if self.nodes[v].se is None:
                continue
            if sums[v] != self.nodes[v].se:
                return False
        for v in self.nodes:
            if self.nodes[v].intersections is None:
                continue
            for target in self.nodes[v].intersections:
                if not self.has_non_intersecting_path(v, set(), 0, target):
                    return False
        return True

    def potential_vals(self, v, valids):
        vals = set()

        if self.nodes[v].se is not None:
            total_v = len(self.nodes[v].edges)
            found_edges = 0
            v_sum = 0
            for z in self.nodes[v].edges:
                if self.edges[(v, z)] is not None:
                    found_edges += 1
                    v_sum += self.edges[(v, z)]
            v_opts = k_sum(valids, self.nodes[v].se - v_sum, total_v - found_edges)
            for opts in v_opts:
                for i in opts:
                    vals.add(i)
        return vals

    def optimal_decisions(self, v, w, valids):

        if self.nodes[v].se is not None and self.nodes[w].se is not None:
            ws = self.potential_vals(w, valids)
            vs = self.potential_vals(v, valids)
            return vs & ws

        elif self.nodes[v].se is not None:
            return self.potential_vals(v, valids)
        elif self.nodes[w].se is not None:
            return self.potential_vals(w, valids)
        return valids

    def update_candidates(self, current_edges):
        candidates = {}
        valids = [i for i in range(1, 25) if i not in self.onstack]
        for v, w in current_edges:
            opts = self.optimal_decisions(v, w, valids)

            if opts:
                if (w, v) in candidates and candidates[(w, v)] == opts:
                    continue
                candidates[(v, w)] = opts

        ordered_dict = dict(sorted(candidates.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=False))
        return ordered_dict

    def get_edges_to_solve(self, current_edges):

        remaining_edges = {}
        for v, w in current_edges:
            if current_edges[(v, w)] is not None:
                assert current_edges[(v, w)] == current_edges[(w, v)]
                continue

            assert current_edges[(v, w)] is None and current_edges[(w, v)] is None
            remaining_edges[(v, w)] = None

        return remaining_edges

    def solve(self):
        progress = len(self.edges) // 2

        def solve_remainder(current_edges):
            nonlocal progress

            edges_to_solve = self.get_edges_to_solve(current_edges)
            candidates = self.update_candidates(edges_to_solve)

            if len(candidates) < len(edges_to_solve) // 2:
                return False
            if len(edges_to_solve) // 2 < progress:
                progress = len(edges_to_solve) // 2
                print(f"Remaining edges to solve: {progress}...")
            for v, w in candidates:
                self.attempts += len(candidates[(v, w)])
                if current_edges[(v, w)] is not None:
                    assert current_edges[(v, w)] == current_edges[(w, v)]
                    continue

                for candidate in candidates[(v, w)]:
                    current_edges[(v, w)] = candidate
                    current_edges[(w, v)] = candidate

                    self.onstack.add(candidate)
                    self.nodes[w].total_sum += candidate
                    self.nodes[v].total_sum += candidate
                    self.filled_edges[v] = self.filled_edges[v] + 1
                    self.filled_edges[w] = self.filled_edges[w] + 1
                    if self.valid():
                        return True
                    if solve_remainder(current_edges):
                        return True
                    else:
                        current_edges[(v, w)] = None
                        current_edges[(w, v)] = None
                        self.onstack.remove(candidate)
                        self.nodes[w].total_sum -= candidate
                        self.nodes[v].total_sum -= candidate
                        self.filled_edges[v] = self.filled_edges[v] - 1
                        self.filled_edges[w] = self.filled_edges[w] - 1
                if (w, v) not in candidates:
                    return False
                if candidates[(w, v)] == candidates[(v, w)]:
                    return False

        return solve_remainder(self.edges)


Nodes = {
    0: Vertex(0, sum_edges=17),
    1: Vertex(1, sum_edges=3),
    2: Vertex(2, None, intersections=[19, 23]),
    3: Vertex(3, None),
    4: Vertex(4, None, intersections=[31]),
    5: Vertex(5, sum_edges=54),
    6: Vertex(6, None, intersections=[6, 9, 16]),
    7: Vertex(7, sum_edges=49),
    8: Vertex(8, None, intersections=[8]),
    9: Vertex(9, sum_edges=60),
    10: Vertex(10, sum_edges=79),
    11: Vertex(11, None),
    12: Vertex(12, 29),
    13: Vertex(13, 75),
    14: Vertex(14, None),
    15: Vertex(15, 25),
    16: Vertex(16, None),
    17: Vertex(17, 39),
}
g = Graph(Nodes)
g.add_edge(0, 1)
g.add_edge(0, 2)
g.add_edge(1, 3)
g.add_edge(2, 3, 12)
g.add_edge(2, 5)
g.add_edge(3, 7)
g.add_edge(4, 5)
g.add_edge(5, 9)
g.add_edge(9, 7)
g.add_edge(7, 8)
g.add_edge(6, 9)
g.add_edge(5, 10)
g.add_edge(9, 10, 24)
g.add_edge(9, 13)
g.add_edge(7, 13, 20)
g.add_edge(10, 11)
g.add_edge(10, 12)
g.add_edge(10, 17, 7)
g.add_edge(12, 17)
g.add_edge(12, 15)
g.add_edge(13, 14)
g.add_edge(13, 15)
g.add_edge(15, 16)
g.add_edge(16, 17)


def dijkstra(graph, edges, start, end):
    # Initialize distances, previous vertices, visited set, and path edges
    distances = {vertex: float('inf') for vertex in graph}
    distances[start] = 0
    previous = {vertex: None for vertex in graph}
    visited = set()
    path_edges = []

    # Initialize priority queue
    pq = [(0, start)]

    while pq:
        # Get the vertex with the minimum distance
        current_distance, current_vertex = heapq.heappop(pq)

        # If the vertex has already been visited, skip it
        if current_vertex in visited:
            continue

        # If the current vertex is the end vertex, break the loop
        if current_vertex == end:
            break

        # Mark the vertex as visited
        visited.add(current_vertex)

        # Explore the neighbors of the current vertex
        for neighbor in graph[current_vertex]:
            # Get the edge weight between the current vertex and the neighbor
            edge_weight = edges[(current_vertex, neighbor)]

            # Calculate the distance to the neighbor through the current vertex
            distance = current_distance + edge_weight

            # If the calculated distance is smaller than the current distance, update it
            if distance < distances[neighbor]:
                distances[neighbor] = distance
                previous[neighbor] = current_vertex
                heapq.heappush(pq, (distance, neighbor))

    # Build the shortest path and collect the edges
    path = []
    current_vertex = end
    while current_vertex is not None:
        path.append(current_vertex)
        if previous[current_vertex] is not None:
            path_edges.append((previous[current_vertex], current_vertex))
        current_vertex = previous[current_vertex]
    path.reverse()
    path_edges.reverse()

    # Return the shortest path, its length, and the edges along the path
    return path, distances[end], path_edges


start = time.perf_counter()
g.solve()
end = time.perf_counter() - start
print(f"graph solved in {end}")
path, length, path_edges = dijkstra(graph=g.g, edges=g.edges, start=3, end=16)


def decode_to_letter(number):
    if 1 <= number <= 24:
        ascii_code = number + 64
        letter = chr(ascii_code)
        return letter
    else:
        return None


s = ""
for v, w in path_edges:
    s += decode_to_letter(g.edges[(v, w)])

print(s)


spent some days, worked on own solution in C#, it runs in ~0.6-0.7s, yours is faster, I know if I chose a different starting node (I went with nodes first approach), then time is (at least) like ~0.04s but I have to figure out how to optimize pre-sorting and not cherry pick, obviously. Also it is possible to optimize your approach from 0.3s to ~0.08s by cutting off an edge. Look at constraint node values and sum nodes values, try to find how they are similar yet exclusive. Let me know if you want details.
